# Disco de estado solido protegido contra escritura en linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

buenas tardes, espero puedan ayudarme con la siguiente duda. Tengo dual boot en mi laptop (windows,ubuntu), resultado que tengo una unidad para mis datos personales, en windows puedes leer y escribir en la unidad, pero si entro en ubuntu solo puedo leer en la unidad mas no escribir, alguien que me ayude con eso.

E googleado y me dice que windows cuando se apaga protege contra escritura las unidades.

Comment: shift + apagar o desactivar el "fast boot" en windows ( power options )

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono!